# auto-fill one column without dragging - Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

How can I fill column A from A1 - A5000 with the same text string "ABC DEF" without dragging it in Google Sheets?

E.g.:

```
A1 ABC DEF
A2 ABC DEF
...
A5000 ABC DEF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try in A1

```
=Arrayformula(if(row(A1:A5000), "ABC DEF",))
```

and see if that helps?

Comment: It works but I use `ArrayFormula` sparingly since it makes the sheets slower. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

For cell `A1`:

`=arrayformula(if(row(A:A)<=5000,"ABC DEF",))`