# 'arrayformula' in Google Sheets vs. in Excel: autofill column

Tags: excel, array-formulas

My old question: *[auto-fill one column without dragging - Google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67616871/auto-fill-one-column-without-dragging-google-sheet/67617118)* and the formula `=Arrayformula(if(row(A1:A5000), "ABC DEF",))` used good in Google Sheets.

Now, I use this formula in Excel, but it doesn’t work.

How can I fix this Excel formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works exactly the same way in Excel 365 if you remove the Arrayformula wrapper:

```
=if(row(A1:A5000), "ABC DEF",)
```

You need to array-enter it in previous versions of Excel using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>